# Npm install package.json files globally

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to use global modules in my isomorphic javascript-projects, I'm using esm and webpack with babel. Reson for this is that I'd like to be able to many experiments, without each project requiring ~100mb for the node_modules folder. I put them on dropbox, and dropbox can't handle so many files. I still want to use package.json and npm for downloading libraries.

I tried to do

npm `install --global`, but the node_modules folder still got populated (but I couldn't run the project). Is it because this command only installs dependencies, not devDependencies locally?

Another idea is to do put a "preinstall" in scripts.
`mkdir -p ~/node_modules/projectname_modules && ln -s ~/node_modules/projectname_modules ./node_modules`

How would you recommend to solve this issue?

EDIT: The last solutions doesn't work, since dropbox will follow symlinks and treat them like regular folders.